# Error: no such table when extending Abstract User Model

Tags: python, django, database, model

I wanted to extend the Base Abstract User Model within Django to have some other Fields:

```
class Student(AbstractUser):
    birth = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    street_number = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(99)])
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    code = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0, MaxValueValidator(9999))])
    address = str(street) + str(street_number) + str(city) + str(code) + str(province)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Adresse: {self.address}'
```

I added this into my settings.py file:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mainApp.Student'
```

But I get an Error saying there is no such table "Student" when trying to load /admin/.
I have made all the migrations using:

```
python manage.py makemigrations mainApp
python manage.py migrate mainApp
```

Error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/

no such table: mainApp_student
```

If y'all need any more infos, please comment!

Answer (score 0):

Try in first time to run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Without put the app name to migration process

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define "address" like this. Database column is not for string concatenation of other columns, nor any calculation. It can cause error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).